# How do I check if all bools in a List of instances of classes is true?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a list of instances of classes like

Imagine you have Slime.cs and you have multiple slimes in a list: List slime = new List();

And each slime class has a bool hasHit; and you wanna check if every slime in the List has hasHit to be true. How would you do that? I understand there's enumerable All but wouldn't that only work for a list/array of bools? I don't know how to do that for a List of instances of a class

I tried to use Enumerable All, I tried using foreach and for loops too

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read [ask] in the [help]. If you tried anything, please show what you tried and how it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<Slime> slimes = new List<Slime>();
bool allShasHit  = slimes.All(slime => slime.hasHit);
```

See [Microsoft All Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-7.0#examples)

Comment: Good answer but I assume OP know's about LINQ already? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/